# Can we simulate Microsoft Authenticator in Java-Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, ui-automation, azure-ad-msal

I am working on Java-Selenium. Our application has implemented Microsoft Authenticator during login.

Now with selenium logging in became an issue because we need to Approve from mobile then only user is redirected to Application home page.

Is there a way to by pass this scenario? Can we use Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) for this scenario. My need is to successfully login with a user having Microsoft Authentication.

Comment: The way to overcome this is to ask your dev guys to mock MSA for your test env so you either have control over that mock using some API or that would be more a stub rather than a mock that would just accept all the attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer : https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java

You might get something out of it.